# How to create a new folder in Phone memory Nokia Qt

Tags: qt, directory, createfile

I am using the following code to create a new folder in the existing "Games" folder, but it just isnt making the folder.

```
QDir dir("C:/Games/MyGame");
if(!dir.exists())
{
    dir.mkdir("C:/Games/MyGame");
}
else
{
    qDebug()<<dir.absolutePath() + " exists";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Games folder in `C:/` [check programmatically whether QDir().exists("C:/Games/) is returning true ].

And also make sure that your `C:/` Folder `doesn't have any file named Games, Because if you have file with same name, the exists function will return false even if the folder is present!`. And `mkdir` will return false!!!

Following piece of code should create the specified directory if its not present.

```
if (QDir().exists("C:/Games/MyGame"))
{
   qDebug()<<dir.absolutePath() + " exists";
}

else
{
   QDir().mkdir("C:/Games/MyGame");
}
```